# Segmentation Fault when using perl regex on large file

Tags: regex, perl, segmentation-fault

I am trying to find and replace pattern on a very large file (43Go) and face some problems with that. I first tried to use sed for this but it does not seems to be optimized for large file, even smaller than 43 Go so i switched to perl.

I have this command :
`perl -0777 -i -pe 's/(public\..)*_seq/\1_id_seq/mg' dump.sql`

But it generates a segmentation fault before exiting and turns my dump of 43 Go into a 0 octet file. The file i am trying to parse is a simple postgresql database dump.

Just as an information :

```
# perl --version

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 67 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Did someone already faced this problem or have any idea about how to solve this ? I would prefer prefer to keep this one line python command but if you have solutions with any other program i will take it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-0777` tells perl to load the whole file into memory (see [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun)). If your memory is less than 43 Go (whatever it is), you'll have to find a way to process it in smaller chunks. For example, try dumping the option, or use `-00` for the "paragraph mode".

Also note that, unlike in sed, you need to use `$1` instead of `\1` in the replacement part of a substitution in Perl.

Comment: the -00 was the solution thanks a lot !
About the $1 instead of \1, are you sure about that ? because runing the same command than before and changing only -0777 to -00 made the pattern works.
Also i'm a bit surprise that it was just a memory issue since i am running this on a 250 Go RAM server.

Comment: @PopHip -- There is a [section](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241) **Warning on \1 Instead of $1** in **perlre** documentation.

Comment: @PopHip -- check configuration of  your server, **How much memory can be allocated to one process**.

Comment: The string is 43 GiB, but you could easily have 20% of overhead. You can count on at least one copy of it being in memory (during reallocation, during substitution). So now we're talking about 103 GiB for 2 or 155 GiB for 3 copies. Ok, not 250, but getting closer...  (Also note that you'd need enough disk space for the original plus the modified version.)